# JqGrid give ID when button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I cant select any rows in my JqGrid so I came across http://www.jqgrid.com/jqgrid/forum/codemerx-jqgrid-for-asp-net/146-can-t-select-rows. Which says I need a ID for every row. I add data to my Grid each time I press a button. I tried giving each row a id with a simple click counter function. But then I when I try to sort all ID's dissapear from the Grid.

Any suggestion how I can solve this?

**Grid**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Configuration for jqGrid Example 1
    $("#table_list_1").jqGrid({
        data: currentTime,
        datatype: "local", //if enabled id dissapear
        height: "100%",
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        loadonce: true,
        sortable: true,
        rowNum: 100,
        rownumbers: true,

        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        colNames: ['Id','Time', 'Note'], // 'Id'
        colModel: [
            {name: 'id', index:'id', width:60, sorttype: 'number', sortable: true},
            { name: 'time', index: 'time', width: 60, sorttype: 'number', sortable: true, editable: true, formatter: "number" },
            { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 60, cellEdit: true, editable: true }

        ],
        pager: "#pager_list_1",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Example jqGrid 1",
        add: true,
        edit: true,
        addtext: 'Add',
        edittext: 'Edit',
        hidegrid: false
    });


    $('#table_list_1').navGrid('#pager_list_1',
            { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true, view: false, position: "left", cloneToTop: true },
            { reloadAfterSubmit: true });

    $('#table_list_1').navButtonAdd('#pager_list_1',
            {
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-pencil",
                title: "Edit",
                caption: "",
                position: "last",

            });
```

**How I add data**

```
var currentTime = [];
var id = 0;
function doKeyDown(e) {

    //test  document.getElementById("currentTimeText").innerHTML = currentTime;
    if (e.keyCode == 49 & wavesurfer.isPlaying()) {
        // KEY = " 1 " 


        id += 1;
        currentTime.push(wavesurfer.getCurrentTime());
        jQuery("#table_list_1").addRowData("", { id: id, time: wavesurfer.getCurrentTime() });

        //test  document.getElementById("currentTimeText").innerHTML = currentTime;

        wavesurfer.addRegion({
            start: wavesurfer.getCurrentTime(),
            end: wavesurfer.getCurrentTime() + 0.1,
            color: '#19aa8d',
            resize: false,
            drag: false,

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Please write in every question the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use, and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The code of `doKeyDown` is unclear. Where you use it? You wrote about some button, but it's unclear which relation have the button the the grid. You use `data: currentTime`, but you don't included any test data.

Comment: Its version 4.6. The doKeyDown add a row with data each time the user press the key "1". In this case it gets time from a song playing and adding a "id" for each time the button is pressed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the sense of the code. In any way it's better to use `undefined` value for `id` if you want that jqGrid generate unique id for you. Why you want to show such strange id to the user (see the column `id`)? Moreover the rowid is **not** the value from `id` property, but the first parameter which you use with the same `""` value. I think it's the main bug in your code.

Comment: The call of `navButtonAdd` looks strange too. One use always `onClickButton` callback in the method.

Comment: I just want it to count each row. "rownumbers: true," is basically doing the job I want but I want to be able to sort on it. Thats why I try to implement my own "rownumbers" I hope it clears up alot of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The rowid is **not** the value from `id` property, but the first parameter which you use with the same `""` value. I think it's the main bug in your code. The call

```
jQuery("#table_list_1").addRowData("", { id: id, time: wavesurfer.getCurrentTime() });
```

should be fixed at least to

```
jQuery("#table_list_1").addRowData(undefined, { id: id, time: wavesurfer.getCurrentTime() });
```

Comment: Atleast id is not dissapearing anymore but now its replaces "1" with jqg1 and "2" with jqg2 etc etc. If i could get this to be 1,2, ,3 ,4 ,5 etc Im all good.

Comment: @Dolle: I asked you to describe what you want to do with the grid. If `id` column should be the order of inserted row, it's OK. I still not understand  why `jqg1` is not good for you? If you would use other parameters or to have two grids on the page then the values will be higher. The user will not see the id. Why you want to change it? For example HTML4 specification don't allow to use id values which starts with number, but all web browsers works without problems with ids like numeric ids. Thus jqGrid generate per default text-prefix + number as the ids. Default prefix is `jqg`.

Comment: @Dolle: One can change the prefix, one can change a lot of other things, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
jQuery("#table_list_1").addRowData(id, { id: id, time:  wavesurfer.getCurrentTime() });
```

So instead of "undefined" I just gave it "id" 
This solved my select problem too.